# Get-ChildItem with GUID in folder path throws ParserError

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

I am using Powershell **2**.0 on computer *vm_remote*. Here i run the command

```
$output = "H:\scripts\" + (get-Date -uformat %Y%m%d) + "output_files.txt"
(get-childitem G:\dum\didum\{12481b3f-12e2-4b55-a5d5-84d3b702036b} -include *.*).count >> $output
```

This leads to the error

```
Bad numeric constant: 30. At H:\scripts\count_files.ps1:4 char:40
+ (get-childitem G:\dum\didum\{30 <<<< f81b3f-12e2-4b55-a5d5-84d3b702036b} -include *.*).count >> $output
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (30:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadNumericConstant
```

Using ` or "" to escape character of GUID does not work.

Running the command

```
Invoke-Command -Computername vm_remote -scriptblock { get-childitem "G:\dum\didum\{12481b3f-12e2-4b55-a5d5-84d3b702036b}" -recurse -include *.* -exclude *.latest }
```

from another computer using remote access (using Powershell **4**.0) I get the following:

```
Bad numeric constant: 30.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (30:String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadNumericConstant
    + PSComputerName        : vm_remote
```

Note: Subfolders also contain GUIDs.

How to fix this?

Comment: `(get-childitem "G:\dum\didum\{12481b3f-12e2-4b55-a5d5-84d3b702036b"}`? Quote the string maybe. Yep thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curly braces have special meaning in PowerShell. I think what is happening is that it is treating the GUID as a `scriptblock` and trying to execute it as code.
 You should be quoting that path string or put it in a string variable to avoid this issue. I get the same issue in 2.0 and doing so in 4.0 nets me no output. Quoting the string in both cases seems to address the issue.

```
(get-childitem "G:\dum\didum\{12481b3f-12e2-4b55-a5d5-84d3b702036b}" -include *.*).count >> $output
```

Not sure about the second example yet though. It works fine for me as long as the path is quoted.

Comment: Thing is: It works for me on another share (H:), but not on G:, but only for this folder (and it subfolders). If I create another folder with subfolders and some files inside on G: it also works (with ""). ACLs are the same on both folders...

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the fact that G: is spanned (as it is a virtual machine with hard disk space added shortly before).